# Postgres bad performance UNION ALL + INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing

In the following scenario a Postgres query is performing very slow. Can anyone help me to pinpoint the problem or the cause of this behavior?

I have 3 different platforms, each uses two tables of the same structure:

1. order (all order information per platform)
2. order_product (all products purchased in each order = customer baskets per platform)

And there is also a global product table which contains product information across all platforms:

3. product

   CREATE TABLE product  (
         product_id character varying(64),
         product_name character varying(512));

I also have views combining all the order and order_product tables from all platforms with UNION ALL.

```
CREATE VIEW order_product_all_platforms AS
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "product_id" 
FROM "public"."order_product_1"
UNION ALL 
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "product_id" 
FROM "public"."order_product_2"
UNION ALL 
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "product_id" 
FROM "public"."order_product_3" ;
```

..

```
CREATE VIEW order_all_platforms AS
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "purchase_date" 
FROM "public"."order_1"
UNION ALL 
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "purchase_date" 
FROM "public"."order_2"
UNION ALL 
SELECT "platform", "order_id", "purchase_date" 
FROM "public"."order_3"
```

The problem arises when I want to combine all these three tables in a query like that:

```
 SELECT "t1.platform", "t1.order_id", t2.product_id, t3.product_name
    FROM order_all_platforms t1 
      INNER JOIN order_product_all_platforms t2 ON t1.platform = t2.platform and t1.order_id = t2.order_id
      INNER JOIN product t3 ON t2.product_id = t3.product_id
 WHERE purchase_date >= '2018-01-01'
```

I think the problematic part of the query plan looks like this. Postgres is performing a sequential scan on product_id despite the fact that an index on product_id exists:

```
->  Hash Join  (cost=23068.58..1963856.51 rows=37164213 width=67)"
        Hash Cond: ((t2.product_id)::text = (t3.product_id)::text)"
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1104593.13 rows=37164213 width=29)"
              ->  Seq Scan on order_product_table1 (cost=0.00..1066147.91 rows=35935991 width=29)"
              ->  Seq Scan on order_product_table2 (cost=0.00..35008.37 rows=1126337 width=32)"
              ->  Seq Scan on order_product_table3 (cost=0.00..3436.85 rows=101885 width=30)"
        ->  Hash  (cost=16209.37..16209.37 rows=548737 width=47)"
              ->  Seq Scan on product t3 (cost=0.00..16209.37 rows=548737 width=47)"
```

What can I do to speed this up?

These are the indexes. The first index also exists on order table, the second index also exists on product table:

```
CREATE INDEX  order_product_table1_index1
  ON  order_product_table1
  USING btree
  (platform_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", order_id);  

CREATE INDEX mat_ order_product_table1_index2
  ON  order_product_table1
  USING btree
  (product_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Comment: Is that index working if you use only one table instead of views? Did you try changing them into partitions instead?

Comment: As I understand it Postgres is performing an Hash Join and uses no index at all when joining the global product table. But how can I increase performance of this kind of query?